# Can't assign user Control (view) to my ContentControl, is always null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I'm trying to display a dynamic user control in my main window. For this I have a **ContentControl** and I am binding it to a property called *MyFooView* which is of type **FooView**.

When the constructor of my main window gets called I am assigning FooView to my UserControl as such:

```
//using statements above...
//public class MainWindowViewModel, implements INotifyPropertyChanged

public FooView MyFooView
{
    get
    {
        return _myfooView;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_myfooView!= null)
        {
            _myfooView= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyFooView));
        }
    }
}
private FooView _myfooView;

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   MyFooView = new FooView(...); //takes in parameters
   //at this point MyFooView is (null)
}
```

My Xaml:

```
   <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,0" Width="880">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyFooView}"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

No matter what MyFooView is always null. Thus, the space where I'm expecting to see my view is empty. Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not have views in view models. That's not MVVM. Use a DataTemplate with a FooView to display foo data.

Comment: @Clemens can you show me an example of that of which takes parameters?

Comment: Not sure what *"of which takes parameters"* is supposed to mean. You may start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: What I mean is, how do I create a datatameplate of a view that its constructor Takes in Parameters?

Comment: Change the view to *not* take constructor arguments. Replace those by properties, preferrably dependency properties that can be bound to properties of a view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always null because you have a null check inside the setter.  You can not assign a value to the property when the field is null, but the field starts off null.

Change from:

```
public FooView MyFooView
{
    get
    {
        return _myfooView;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_myfooView!= null)
        {
            _myfooView= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyFooView));
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
public FooView MyFooView
{
    get
    {
        return _myfooView;
    }
    set
    {
        _myfooView= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyFooView));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could perform a null check on the `value`, which is perhaps what you intended to do to begin with, as such:

```
public FooView MyFooView
{
    get
    {
        return _myfooView;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value!= null)
        {
            _myfooView= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyFooView));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, what [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) said is exactly right.  Even though this should fix your problem, this is poor design if you are attempting to use the MVVM pattern.

Comment: wow, that was a MAJOR slight. Thanks for catching that. I will take @Clemens advice and set this up where I am setting MyFooView as a DataTemplate

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the wonderful world of logic errors, where the code always compiles, and yet somehow never works the way it was intended.  This sort of thing can be easy to miss, so don't feel too bad.